# Selector de adaptadores de red en C

Tags: c, windows, networking

Necesito printar la información requerida de un adaptador de red, previamente seleccionado de un listado (mediante scanf aunque me sugieren leecad, que desconozco del todo) y, en mi caso, extraerla de un archivo ".txt" que previamente he redireccionado, aunque estoy atento a otros enfoques.

A continuación dejo el planteamiento de mi código a ver si me podéis echar un cable en el último bloque, que es donde muestro mayor problema:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char extraer_info(const char* adaptador);

void main(void) {
    FILE* fp;
    char termAdaptador[BUFSIZ] = "Adaptador";
    char* p, * p2;
    char str[100], line[256], adaptador[100];
    const char* terms[] = {
    "IPv4",
    "subred",
    "Puerta",
    "Servidores DNS",
    NULL
    };

    // Redirection to ip.out.txt in order to gather the info I want
    strcpy(str, "> ip.out.txt ");
    strcat(str, "ipconfig /allcompartments /all");
    system(str);

    // Listing the adapters
    fp = fopen("ip.out.txt", "r");
    printf("\n    Los adaptadores de red disponibles son los siguientes:\n\n");
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp)) {
        if (strstr(line, termAdaptador) != NULL)
            printf(line);

    }

    // Scanf to choose my adapter and display its info
    printf("Escribe el adaptador deseado: ");
    scanf("%s", adaptador);
    printf("\n\n");
    char adapt_info = extraer_info(adaptador);
}

char extraer_info(const char* adaptador)
{
    FILE* fp;
    const char* const Delim = "Media = ";
    const char* terms[] = {
    "IPv4",
    "subred",
    "Puerta",
    "Servidores DNS",
    NULL
 };

    fp = fopen("ip.out.txt", "r");
    char line[256];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp))
        for (const char** p = terms; *p; ++p)
            if (strstr(line, *p))
                fputs(line, stdout);

    //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Estás seguro que eso funciona? Estás ejecutando la siguiente línea en la consola: `>> ip.out.txt ipconfig /allcompartments /all`. A qué función l`eecad` te refieres?

Comment: Editado nuevamente, con algo más de información y detalle, con nueva reformulación de mi código, además de estar comentada para especificar mejor mis dudas, que residen mayormente en el último bloque.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema con el último código? ¿Qué tiene? ¿Qué errores sale?

Comment: Efectivamente, el código no era el correcto. Llevo unos días peleándome con varios. He comprobado y éste es más fidedigno, pero tengo problemas reencaminando la parte final para extraer el párrafo que haga mención al adaptador en cuestión (mediante el scanf("%s", adaptador); quiero almacenar la variable que haga referencia al párrafo siguiente que printará, es la única manera que se me ocurre para obtener los detalles que necesito individualmente...).

Comment: @Santos ¿Cómo está guardada la información en el archivo? Es decir, tiene un formato en especifico?

Comment: ¿En cuanto al txt donde leo? Sí, guarda como un ipconfig /allcompartments /all lanzado a cmd normal, es decir, los nombres de cada adaptador seguidos de dos puntos, dos espacios (\n\n), las líneas de información y dos saltos de línea más. ¿Te refieres a eso? Si necesitas más información sólo tienes que decírmelo.

Comment: Te propongo que la información la guardes con este formato: `IPv4, subred, Puerta, Servidor DNS`.

Comment: Al usar este formato, es más sencillo, porque al leer el archivo sabemos que el delimitador es una coma(`,`). Entonces simplemente puedes usar la función [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) para extraer la información por separado.